# making reusable component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code, want to remove the repeated content code inside  `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup` to a separate file - does not look straight forward to pass props to and fro from child/parent, how do I do it? is it do-able?

```
   <div className="container">
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
      <span key={this.state.showChild1} className="plus_icon">
        <a onClick={() => this.onClick('child1')}>
          <Img className={this.state.showChild1 ? 'plus_icon' : 'minus_icon'} />
        </a>
      </span>
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    {this.state.child1 ? <Child1-New /> : <div onClick={() => this.onClick('child1')}><Child1 /></div>}
  </div>

  <div className="container">
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
      <span key={this.state.showChild2} className="plus_arrow">
        <a onClick={() => this.onClick('child2')}>
          <img className={this.state.child2 ? 'plus_icon' : 'minus_icon'} />
        </a>
      </span>
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    {this.state.child2 ? <Child2-New /> : <div onClick={() => this.onClick('child2')}><Child2 /></div>}
  </div>

onClick(name) {
    if (name === 'child1') {
      this.setState({
        showChild1: !this.state.showChild1,
      });
    } else if (name === 'child2') {
      this.setState({
        showChild2: !this.state.showChild2,
      });
}
```

planning to achieve something like:

```
<div className="container">
   <ToggleView />
    {this.state.child2 ? <Child2-New /> : <div onClick={() => this.onClick('child2')}><Child2 /></div>}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Node.js it's quite simple to manage your components in separate JS files.

Create a new JS file - ToggleView.js - as an example.

```
var React = require('react');
module.exports = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            ... Your markup etc here
        </div>
    );
});
```

And then you can require it from within the JS where you want to use it:

```
var ToggleView = require('ToggleView.js');
```

And then use it:

```
<div className="container">
    <ToggleView />
</div>
```

Secondly, if your state is managed at the parent which you need your children to have access to, you can simply prop down to them.

```
function thisFunc(val) {
    // do something
};
```

Prop the function to the child

```
<ToggleView handleFunc={this.thisFunc} />
```

And in ToggleView.js, if you needed your  to trigger on click:

```
...
  <a onClick={this.prop.handleFunc}>
      <img ... />
  </a>
...
```

In this scenario, we prop **thisFunc** down to the child which will allow you to set the logic at the parent, whether you need to set state or whatever.

Hopefully this helps!